Some add events are missing when copying many files into watched folder
Chokidar Version: 3.5.2
When copying many files, e.g. hundreds of files into the watched folder, I found number of add events is not equal to the total number of files, i.e. some add events are missing.
Following is the configuration of chokidar.
let defaultOptions = {
    ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../, // ignore dotfiles
    persistent: true,
    depth: 99,
    alwaysStat: true,
    awaitWriteFinish: {
        stabilityThreshold: 3000,
        pollInterval: 100
    },
    ignorePermissionErrors: false,
    ignoreInitial: true,
    atomic: true // or a custom 'atomicity delay', in milliseconds (default 100)
};

I have also tried with usePolling = true. but, it didn't work for me. could anyone help us with this?
